# VBA Excel: Looping existing groups

Tags: vba, excel

If possible, how would you execute a loop for each group that you have created in Excel? For example, I have about 5,000 rows that I grouped using a common Julian day (column C). Within each of these groups there are   different start and stop times (E and F). For all the times in these groups I would like to find the minimum (start time) and the maximum (stop time). I'm not sure where to start with this code because I have no idea how to access or point to the individual groups I have created. Below is an example of how I have my worksheet structured. I would have attached and image but I can't because of my new status to stackoverflow. Any help would be appreciated!

> A -------------- B----------- C------------D--------------------------------------E-----------------F
>
> Project----- Vessel--------Day--------Line--------------------------------Min Time------Max Time
>
> Sheet A------XXXX -------192---- 0008-192-2A1-0000_-_0001---6:56:32AM---7:26:45AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in a formula if you wanted.

Label column G "First Group Start Time" and H "Last Group End Time" or something to that effect.

Then, in G2, put this formula as an array formula (ctrl + shift + enter), and drag-copy down to the end of your data:

```
=MIN(IF($C:$C=$C2,$E:$E))
```

Then repeat for H2 with a similar array formula:

```
=MAX(IF($C:$C=$C2,$F:$F))
```

Please let me know if this works for you, as it is untested.

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the feedback. However, I should have been more specific. I also was able to obtain the result I needed with pivot tables. However, I would like to write a program in VBA editor to run each time I get a new set of data. Basically create a tool for myself. Any advice on how to write some code using VBA to loop through individual groups that have been created in Excel?

Comment: Thank you for your input and sorry for the late response. This did work and I used it to organize my data before simplifying it further using a pivot table.